# systemd execute python script to mount NFS driver is not working

Tags: python, linux, mount, systemd, nfs

I wrote a systemd script and python script for auto detect mounting.

Systemd Script:

```
[Unit]
Description=TAD_Client - TAD WebService
After=network.target
[Service]
User=root
Type=forking
ExecStart=/data/.services/autoconfig.sh start
ExecReload=/data/.services/autoconfig.sh restart
ExecStop=/data/.services/autoconfig.sh stop
PrivateTmp=true
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Shell Script(part):

```
export SHELL=/bin/bash
case "$1" in
"start" )
    echo "configuration service start"
    exec "/usr/bin/python" /data/.services/AutoConfiguration.py run &
;;
"stop" )
    echo "configuration service stop"
    exec "/usr/bin/python" /data/.services/AutoConfiguration.py stop
;;
"restart" )
    echo "restart configuration service"
    exec "/usr/bin/python" /data/.services/AutoConfiguration.py stop
    exec "/usr/bin/python" /data/.services/AutoConfiguration.py run &
;;
```

Python Script(part):

```
def mount_peu_server(self):
    mount_command = 'mount -t nfs ' + server_ip.addr + ':/mnt /mnt'
    p = subprocess.Popen(mount_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    self.log_error(out)
    self.log_error(err)
```

When I use systemd to start the script as a service, the mount command is not working, but if i execute the python script file directly, the mount command can be executed successfully.

I have checked the output and err output, subprocess returns nothing. I think it could be a privilege problem, but this service is running by root user, which should not require any privilege anymore.

Comment: I don't know if it's the source of your problem, but you are misusing the `exec` statement. It doesn't make sense to combine `exec` with `&`, nor does it make sense to call `exec` twice in succession (because the first will replace the shell with a new command and the second will never execute).

Comment: Also, consider adding some logging to `autoconfig.sh` and `AutoConfiguration.py` to confirm that everything is being called when you expect with the arguments you expect.